# iptables doesn't like arguments

Tags: debian, iptables

I'm setting up a debian 10 server and its my first time using iptables, but it seems iptables just doesn't like basic arguments. I went through the manpage and tried stuff from https://phoenixnap.com/kb/iptables-tutorial-linux-firewall

```
~# iptables –A INPUT –j DROP
Bad argument `–A'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

~# iptables –A INPUT –p tcp ––dport 80 –j ACCEPT
Bad argument `–A'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

~# iptables –A INPUT –i lo –j ACCEPT
Bad argument `–A'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

~# iptables --version
iptables v1.8.2 (legacy)
```

whats happening here?

the manpage knows about -A :

```
SYNOPSIS
   iptables [-t table] {-A|-C|-D} chain rule-specification
```

something is completely nuts here. Eiter me or iptables or both m)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have copied an invalid char instead of a hyphen, probably from a website.

take a look at these two characters:

```
–
-
```

The first is what you have in your parameter, the second is a proper hyphen you get when you type it with your keyboard. `–A` should be `-A` instead.